# JPA to JAXB issue

Tags: jpa, jaxb, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, hyperjaxb

I have entities which are created from eclipseLink.I am trying to use the same objects to get generate an xml.I have a primarykey reference inside a class and I am not sure what annotation I need to use to get the desired xml.
 I have

```
public class ABC implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private NamePK id;

@XmlElement
private String address1;

    @XmlElement
private String address1;
```

...
}

```
 public class NamePK implements Serializable {
//default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="county")
@XmlTransient
private String county;

@Column(name="NAME")
@XmlElement
private String name;
```

....

}

How should the annotation at the NamePk be for me to get the xml output as

```
 <name>XXX</name>
 <Address1>YYY</Address1>
 <Address2>ZZZ</Address2>
```

Do I need annotate at both the levels of the PK?(Class Level and reference)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead, and a member of the JAXB 2 ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) expert group.

You can use the MOXy JAXB implementation in EclipseLink to accomplish this:

**ABC**

You can use `@XmlPath(".")` to have the embedded ID marshal/unmarshal at the same level as your `ABC` class:

```
public class ABC implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @XmlPath(".")
    private NamePK id;

    @XmlElement
    private String address1;

    @XmlElement
    private String address1;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/MOXy
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html

Comment: That didn't work for me. The PK is still under his own level. Do i have to do something in the PK class?

Comment: My fault. Didn't use jaxb.properties as pointed out in some of your other answers.

Comment: But still, the unmarshalling doesn't seem to work. Need to investigate further

Comment: It works, but it also duplicates the id fields in the json. Any idea why ?